# Dragged HTML element to follow the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Consider the following markup and script:

```
<div id="container">
  <div draggable="true">
    <button type="button" id="button">Drag me!</button>
  </div>
  <div draggable="true"></div>
  <div draggable="true"></div>
  <div draggable="true"></div>
  <div draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

```
let dragged;

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e)
{
  dragged = e.parentNode;
  // What to do here?
});

let divs = document.querySelectorAll("#container div");
for (let i=0; i<div.length; i++)
{
  divs[i].addEventListener("dragleave", function(e)
  {
    if (this.nextSibling == dragged) // move downwards
    {
      this.parentNode.insertBefore(dragged, this);
    }
    else // move upwards
    {
      this.parentNode.insertBefore(dragged, this.nextSibling);
    }
  });
}
```

I have several of these `div` elements below each other inside a container. The `button` element is only appended to one `div` at a time.

**1)** I want the `div` element with the `button` inside it to pop out of its place and follow the mouse cursor on drag.

**2)** When the `div` moves on top of a neighbor `div`, I want that `div` to slide into the empty space.

Is there a vanilla JS solution?

Comment: mate, this is not a coding service. Show us what you have done so far please.

Comment: I have updated my question. This is all I have. It works as expected. What I want to know is how to animate this.

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/, this can help you

Comment: It gives a 404 error.

Comment: have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN, posting here because OP owner cannot access.

```js
var dragged;

/* events fired on the draggable target */
document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {

}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  // store a ref. on the dragged elem
  dragged = event.target;
  // make it half transparent
  event.target.style.opacity = .5;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
  // reset the transparency
  event.target.style.opacity = "";
}, false);

/* events fired on the drop targets */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
  // prevent default to allow drop
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
  // highlight potential drop target when the draggable element enters it
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "purple";
  }

}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
  // reset background of potential drop target when the draggable element leaves it
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "";
  }

}, false);

document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
  // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
  event.preventDefault();
  // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "";
    dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
    event.target.appendChild(dragged);
  }

}, false);
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}

.dropzone {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blueviolet;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone">
  <div id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">
    This div is draggable
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

Comment: I have seen this tutorial on MDN, but it does not answer my questions.

Comment: which is the part that you are missing here? 1 and 2 is covered

Comment: 1) The actual element does not follow the mouse cursor, only its screenshot. 2) I don't want to move an element from one container into the other. I want to rearrange them.